# Combining two awk commands into one

Tags: awk

Currently, I'm using the following two awk commands connected with one pipeline:

```
awk 'sub(/([^ ]+[ ]+){4}[^ ]+[ ]/,"")'  ~/.bash_eternal_history | awk '!a[$0]++'
```

I want to combine them in one awk invocation.  How should I revise the commands above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like your code:

```
awk 'sub(/([^ ]+[ ]+){4}[^ ]+[ ]/,"") && !a[$0]++'  ~/.bash_eternal_history
```

The first part returns false if the pattern does not match, the second condition returns false if the replaced string is already in the hash.

**A simplified example**

```
echo -e "xlmx\nxlmx\nyyy\nxlmx"|awk 'sub("lm", "") && !a[$0]++'
```

Output:

```
xx
```

**Notes**

- With older [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) (like 3.1.5) `--re-interval` has to be used to enable `{n,m}` RE interval expressions. In newer version it is on by default as OP noted.
- The RE could be reduced a bit. `[ ]` is identical to a simple space, so the pattern could be like `/([^ ]+ +){4}[^ ]+ /`. Or to extend the pattern, use `[[:space:]]` to enable all kind of white space as separator.
- Actually it turned out that in some older [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) there is some RE problem. The second line does not return any row with [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) v3.1.5, but it does work with newer [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) v4.1.3.

---

```
$ echo -e "al\na b  c \n a"|awk --re-interval '/([^ ]+ +){2}/'
a b  c 
$ echo -e "al\na b  c \n a"|awk --re-interval '/([^ ]+[ ]+){2}/'
```

Comment: " man gawk " gives me the following on the "--re-interval" option:  They are enabled by default, but this option remains for
              use with --traditional.  So, when using gawk, this is just for my case, the  "--re-interval" option is enabled by default.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @HongyiZhao Thanks for the comment! I modified my Notes. I tested with older `gawk` and it seems the default behavior has been changed since 2005 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the second script to the first separated by `;`

```
awk '{sub(/([^ ]+[ ]+){4}[^ ]+[ ]/,"")}; !a[$0]++'  ~/.bash_eternal_history
```

Note: The first action, `sub` should be placed in `{}` to prevent `awk` from throwing the output twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But there are some typos in your reply.  It should be revised as follows: awk '{sub(/([^ ]+[ ]+){4}[^ ]+[ ]/,"")}; !a[$0]++'  ~/.bash_eternal_history.

Comment: @HongyiZhao Ohh...sorry for that. Hope it helps

Comment: IMHO this code is not identical to OP's request. This will print a line even if no RE match were found by `sub`.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R In fact, the semicolon, ; , is not need here. So the following one is OK: awk '{sub(/([^ ]+[ ]+){4}[^ ]+[ ]/,"")} !a[$0]++' ~/.bash_eternal_history. Regards